# What determines what races a slaver can provide?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

When encountering a slaver ship, you have a couple of options to acquire a new crew member.  You can buy slaves, fight to receive a slave as a bribe, or kill the slaver crew to gain your choice of slaves.

Is there anything that affects which races are involved, or is it completely random?

For example:  If I am in an Engi controlled sector, am I more likely to get an Engi from slavers?

Comment: That's been my experience, but I can't say I've gather statistically-significant data.

Comment: I can't remember if I've run into a slaver in anything but a civilian sector - and that the crew you get is completely random. They don't even look after their own race - (I've gotten a Mantis slave from a Mantis slaver for example) Best option is use a teleporter to free a slave (blue choice). You'll gain the crew and the slavers will turn hostile. You can then kill off their crew/ weaken them to the point of surrender, with a chance of getting another crew member.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple different ways to resolve a slaver encounter which will result in new crew members:

**[Friendly Slaver](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Friendly_Slaver)**

- Buy a slave.

  - Receive 1 **random** crew member.
- Using a level 2+ Teleporter.

  - Outcomes 1: Receive 1 **random** crew member *and* fight the slavers.
  - Outcomes 2: Receive 1 **random** crew member *and* fight the slavers.
  - Outcomes 3: No crew member up front, but fight the slavers.
- Fight the slaver scum.

  - See below.

**[Pirate Slaver](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Pirate_Slaver)**

- Fight the slaver scum.

  - See below.
- If you have level 6+ Engines, you can attempt to outrun the slavers.  If this fails, you will fight the salvers.

**Fighting the slavers:**

The outcome of the fight can lead to a new crew member even if you got one through the teleporter dialogue option.

- Slavers surrender.

  - Receive 1 **random** crew member.
- Kill the slaver crew.

  - Outcome 1: Receive 1 **random** crew member.
  - Outcome 2: Receive **your choice** of a Rock, Mantis, or Engi crew member.
  - Outcome 3: No crew member.
- Destroy the ship.

  - No crew members.

**All in all, crew members you receive are of a random race, but there is an option to get your choice of Rock, Mantis, or Engi if you do things correctly.**

Answer (score 1):

In my (limited) experience, if you kill the crew of the slaver you get your pick of the slaves, which is one of each main race (Engi, Human, Rock, Mantis). That suggests to me that the common races are always present, and if you do one of the other possible approaches (teleport, accept surrender) then you get a slave randomly selected from that pool.

Comment: I have gotten Zoltan slaves before.

Comment: I've never had this option come up after killing off the crew. It's always one of three scenarios for me: 1) The weapons fire & damage to the ship has killed off all the slaves. 2) Most of the slaves are dead, you find one alive and unconscious. after treating his injuries he offers to join your crew. 3) You free the slaves, most want to be dropped off at the nearest planet, one offers to join up with you.

Comment: @Robotnik I've gotten this option multiple times, you have to beat them via boarding though.

Comment: @spartacus - I pretty much only beat them by boarding, if I can. It must just be luck of the draw for me

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember there isn't any order or rule for that. It looks like it is **randomly generated** - [wikia suggest the same](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Pirate_Slaver).

I have only one "*rule*" that come to my mind. I can't remember that I have slave that was the same race as slaver ship would suggest - but this might be a coincidence.